# Getting null value with Retrofit in android

Tags: java, android

ApiInterface

```
public interface ApiInterfaceTemp
 {
@GET("bf10b0f9631a80747ebfe6a674c0/37.8267,-122.4233")
Call<TempDbDailyData> getTopRatedMovies();
}
```

Mainactivity

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temp_new);

    ApiInterfaceTemp apiInterfaceTemp = ApiClientTemp.getClient().create(ApiInterfaceTemp.class);
    Call<TempDbDailyData> call = apiInterfaceTemp.getTopRatedMovies();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<TempDbDailyData>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<TempDbDailyData> call, Response<TempDbDailyData> response)
        {
            String temp = response.body().getSummary();
            textView.setText(temp);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<TempDbDailyData> call, Throwable t)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
        }
    });

}
```

I had the mainactivity and Api added here.Getting null value for variable temp.Please let me know where i am going wrong

Comment: have you checked if the TempDbDailyData in the response body is not null ? if not, when you're getting the Summary you're obtaining null value because of a bad parsing. Are you using gson?

Comment: retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

Comment: Check if the attribute Summary in your TempDbDailyData has the same name in the json response. If you're using different names you have to use the @SerializedName() annotation